# add filters and facets to an existing gallery

Tags: e-commerce, filter, faceted-search

I am creating a CMS for an ecommerce website template, the site is can be used for selling almost anything, and I want to add an option to create a faceted navigation, in order to better refine search results.

The issue I am facing:
what would be the best way to let a website owner add filters and facets to an existing gallery?

Edit: what important steps are there when adding facets navigation to an existing ecommerce?

Comment: This is a very broad question. Can you share any mockups or wireframes so that we can see what ideas you've considered so far?

Comment: Hi Matt, I have narrowed down the questions, its a work in progress, so as soon as I will have wireframes, I will add them, how do I get my question out of hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow shop owners to add in custom filters you will need to consider a few things.

What options may people need (colour, size)
The type of input required (swatches, checkbox, slider)
Values and ranges ([brown,black], £0 - £100)

You will then need to think about how these can be managed from the back end. For example you will want the ability to add filters and edit existing filters.

You will probably need to consider allowing the user to create a description or an alias for these.

Managing how these facets are displayed on the front end should always be driven from the product data itself.

Hope this helps!